# How to modify the third-party package name on which Android programs depend？

Tags: android

After Android SDK development and release, there is a conflict between integrated third-party libraries. Is there any way to modify the package name of the third-party library that the SDK depends on when it is released, such as shadow https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow, but it only supports jar and does not support AAR

Comment: If you have a way, please let me know. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify third-party package name if you have downloaded, it's android library and add to your project manually.

If you have `synced Gradle version` then you can't even edit a single line of the package.

and this is the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/8XCV7vbwB88). how to change package name of a project and it will work as same as in android library.

and [here](https://youtu.be/M5CHOynHm30) . it will show how to add JAR file in android studio.